# How does kernel resolve a filename to an inode?

Tags: filesystems

According to this [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/vfs.txt), dentries are never stored on disk. I believe a directory is an inode whose data block contains just the names of files and inode block number (see image below). But how does the kernel really resolve `/home/foo/hello.c` from `/` all the way? i.e. how does the kernel know which inode is `/` or `/var`?

```
Directory Entry Cache (dcache)
------------------------------

The VFS implements the open(2), stat(2), chmod(2), and similar system
calls. The pathname argument that is passed to them is used by the VFS
to search through the directory entry cache (also known as the dentry
cache or dcache). This provides a very fast look-up mechanism to
translate a pathname (filename) into a specific dentry. Dentries live
in RAM and are never saved to disc: they exist only for performance.

The dentry cache is meant to be a view into your entire filespace. As
most computers cannot fit all dentries in the RAM at the same time,
some bits of the cache are missing. In order to resolve your pathname
into a dentry, the VFS may have to resort to creating dentries along
the way, and then loading the inode. This is done by looking up the
inode.
```

[image]

Comment: @jsotola VFS is the kernel's abstraction of what we think of "filesystem".

Comment: this may or may not help https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/416/notes/12-filesystems.html